# Using google-vr unity plufin without using cardboard view

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-vr

**Background:** Hey, I am developing a VR game for mobile similar to pokemonGo. I tried using unity's Input.gyro.attitude but it doesn't work very well on some devices (S6 for example).

I searched and found google-vr, that is built for google carboard I installed it and added the GvrControllerMain prefab and it tracks the gyroscopic movement perfectly for all devices.

**My question is:** is there any way to use this sdk but disabling the cardboard view? I just want to get the tracking out of it.

**Versions:** I'm using unity 5.6.2f1 and the latest version of google-vr